# How Do I Get This Program To Draw 10 Rectangles in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, pygame

> I'm trying to get this to program to print out 10 Rectangles that
>   move using a for loop. With what I've printed out below it it's only
>   printing out 1 moving rectangle. I believe my issue lies in lines
>   67-70? Does anyone know how to get this program to print out 10
>   rectangles?

```
import pygame
from random import randrange 

#Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

#Set width and height of screen
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Classes")

class Rectangle():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.color = [0, 255, 0]
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.change_x
        self.y = self.y + self.change_y     


#Loop until user clicks close
done = False

#Manage how fast screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_list = []
for i in range(10):

    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_object.x = randrange(0, 701)
    my_object.y = randrange(0, 501)
    my_object.change_x = randrange(-3, 3)
    my_object.change_y = randrange(-3, 3)
    my_object.width = randrange(20, 71)
    my_object.height = randrange(20, 71)
    my_object.color = [0, 255, 0]
    my_list.append(my_object)

#Main Program Loop
while not done:
    #Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    #Game logic goes here

    #Screen clearing code or background image goes here
    screen.fill(black)

    #drawing code goes here
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        my_object.draw(screen)
        i = i + 1
    my_object.move()

    #update and display drawn screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    #limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

#close the window and quit
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the drawing code loop from

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_object.draw(screen)
    i = i + 1
my_object.move()
```

to

```
for my_object in my_list
    my_object.draw(screen)
    my_object.move()
```

In this bit of code, the section `for my_object in my_list` goes through the objects in "my_list", one at a time, and names it "my_object". You need to draw each object, and move each object, so draw and move have to be called from within the loop. If you called them from outside the loop, it would only happen once.